# How does a branch target buffer reduce latency?

Tags: branch, cpu-architecture

I guess there is something I'm just not getting. I believe I understand the concept behind a BTB... but I don't get how it is useful.

So the BTB, in the IF stage of a pipelined processor, allows us to know the likely target of a branch. This is knowledge we would typically discover in the ID stage... so we have it one stage earlier.

But... so what? What do we DO with this information? How does it makes our pipeline any faster?

Comment: Even for such a shallow scalar pipeline, a lack of BTB (or delayed branch) would mean that taken branches have an CPI of 2 (one flushed instruction). With roughly one branch in every five instructions and about half of them taken, CPI without a BTB would be 1.1 (0.9 * 1 CPI + 0.1 * 2 CPI). For modern high performance processors the delay between beginning fetch and calculating the address is greater than 1 cycle *and* multiple instructions are fetched per cycle. Indirect jumps would generally suffer an even greater penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance impact of the BTB is **more obvious in super scalar processors**. Super scalar means that the processor has multiple ID (instruction decoders). For example 4th generation Intel Core processors (Haswell) have **4 decoders**, ARM A15 parts have 3 decoders, etc.

*Being able to predict which branch your code will take, will allow you to fetch and decode multiple instructions **in advance** and try to fill all the decoders, without stopping the pipeline*.

Also by knowing the taken branch the processor can reorder the incoming instructions speculatively.

If we have no branch prediction (with a BTB) the CPU needs to wait the evaluation of the conditional instructions and meanwhile, the rest of the ID's will not do anything while the condition is assessed, not taking advantage of the "super-scalarness" :).

Why is branch prediction important ... it helps the CPU to **execute as much instructions per cycle as possible**. For example, Haswell CPU's could theoretically execute 4 instructions in the same cycle. BTB helps for that.

Comment: If there was no branch predictor the CPU could still fetch and execute down the not-taken path.  It would just need to squash the instructions if the branch was taken.

Comment: @CraigAnderson, if that's what you're suggesting ... I'm not sure if you can execute in parallel instructions on both branches because they use the same data / addresses. You can execute at a point just on a taken path.

Comment: VAndrei @VAndrei - actually, it is possible to execute down both paths. [This paper] (http://gram.eng.uci.edu/~swallace/papers_wallace/pdf/ISCA-98-TME.pdf) talks about the advantages of doing so.  It isn't easy though.

Comment: @CraigAnderson thank you for the paper link. Very interesting lecture. I don't think however that this feature made it in current architectures - please correct me if I'm wrong. After all, in MTP solution, you keep one ID/EXEC stages busy with work that won't be used. Branch prediction generally has >90% efficiency so this will make it better than the MTP solution.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about branches in a stream of instructions, there are three questions:

1. Is this instruction a branch instruction?
2. If this is a conditional branch, will the branch be taken?
3. If the branch is taken or is an unconditional branch, from where should the next instruction be fetched?  What is the branch **target**?

Since fetching instructions is at the head of the pipeline, answering these questions as early in the pipeline as possible is critical to performance in today's highly superscaler processors.

The **branch predictor** tries to predict the answer to question #2.
The **BTB** tries to predict the answer to question #3.  Though often people lump the BTB in when they talk about the "branch predictor".

Answer (score 0):

With that information the CPU can start the process of fetching, decoding, and speculatively executing the code at the branch target sooner.